# How can I use ReadableByteChannel to get file contents and store it in byteBuffer?

Tags: java, bytebuffer

Below is the code that I have written. I want to do the simple thing, storing binary file data into byteBuffer.

```
File file = new File(fileName);
try {
    ReadableByteChannel channel = new FileInputStream(fileName).getChannel();
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(file.length());

    // How can use buf.read to get all the contents?

} catch (Exception e){

}
```

I was wondering

1. how can I use `read` to get all data from channel and store it in ByteBuffer
2. if there is more elegant way to allocate `ByteBuffer`, other than using `File` object to get the length of the file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [ReadableByteChannel Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ReadableByteChannel.html)

> read(ByteBuffer dst)
>   An attempt is made to read up to r bytes from the channel, where r is the number of bytes remaining in the buffer, that is, dst.remaining(), at the moment this method is invoked.

So ... `channel.read(buf);`

As for your second question, if you want to read the entire contents of the file into memory at once that seems like a reasonable approach.

Comment: Thank you very much. So, allocating the ByteBuffer with length of the file will safely read all file contents to the ByteBuffer?

Comment: I have not tried it personally, but I do not see any reason as to why it wouldn't; that's how much data you need to read. (The issue isn't one of safety but one of "did I get all the data in one fell swoop")

Comment: I don't think this works reliably. A ReadableByteChannel has every right to return less than the remaining bytes. From the Javadoc "A read operation might not fill the buffer, and in fact it might not read any bytes at all." I think you need to write your own version of readFully.

Comment: @ChristianSchlichtherle - Keep reading the rest of that paragraph rather than stopping there. Specifically the part about a file channel.

Comment: @Brian Roach: "...a file channel cannot read any more bytes than remain in the file." - that's all it says there. I know that a FileChannel will fulfill the entire read request, but in spirit of defensive programming, I would not rely on this. It could all to easily break the next time someone is using that code to read from another channel.

Answer (score 10):

I prefer to use memory mapping.

```
FileChannel channel = new FileInputStream(fileName).getChannel();
ByteBuffer buf = channel.map(MapMode.READ_ONLY,0,channel.size());
```

If the file is greater than 2 GB, you have to have more than one mapping.  On the plus side this takes around 10 ms regardless of size and doesn't use much heap or direct memory regardless of the size of the file.